# Spring config trouble

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm trying to do a web app for the first time.

I'm trying to integrate hibernate and spring without success, maybe you can tell me what am I doing wrong

this is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
       xmlns:int-security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security/spring-integration-security-2.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
>


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mac" />

    <bean id="pooledDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" >  
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>  
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>  
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>    
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />  
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="macPU"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />     
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

this my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and finally persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="macPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!--<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>-->
        <class>com.mac.htest.map.TipoHabitacion</class>
        <class>com.mac.htest.map.TipoIdentificacion</class>
        <class>com.mac.htest.map.Habitacion</class>
        <class>com.mac.htest.map.Cliente</class>
        <class>com.mac.htest.map.Reserva</class>
        <class>com.mac.htest.map.Nacionalidad</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="$far374"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my main problem(and I don't know if the only one) is that I can't @Inject classes.

I thank in advance your help with this(and maybe additional suggestions)

Comment: I am not sure if you are using it already. But, if you need to use spring beans, aren't you supposed to use Delegating Variable resolver in your faces-context.xml?
`<application>
    <variable-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
    </variable-resolver>
</application>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `@Inject` via Spring of things like `@Autowire` you need to heed the [directions in the Spring docs (3.0)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) (and [current version](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations)). You include neither the Spring version, nor your pom file, nor how you're trying to use `@Inject`, but I doubt you're including the JSR-330 jar as a dependency.